# How to make angled SVGs interlock

Tags: html, css, svg

I currently have two SVGs that were designed to interlock with eachother but the higher SVG (The first in the imgur link) acts as if it were a rectangle and "pushes" the lower SVG (The second picture in the imgur link) down away from it and they end up with a large space between them (The third imgur link). I have only changed the width of the second SVG in the code so far. Without manually aligning them, which would ruin my page's responsiveness, is there a way to give the SVG a smaller hitbox or similar?

https://imgur.com/a/YtBuso4

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1920 1250">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: #190eae;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <path id="bali-beautiful-beauty-433539" class="cls-1" d="M0,0H1920V1080L0,1250Z"/>
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 960 1080.021" id="sectiona">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        opacity: 0.7;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g id="Group_78" data-name="Group 78" transform="translate(-488 -3248.979)">
    <path id="Path_26" data-name="Path 26" class="cls-1" d="M-1-16.511l960-85.021V978.489l-960-85Z" transform="translate(489 3350.511)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Thank you

Comment: As it stands, your question is quite unclear. Could you please edit it and include some code; ideally a [mcve]?

Comment: Do the two SVGs need to "move" in relation to each other? If yes, in what way? If static, should there be a distance between them?

Comment: No, they should be touching and "slot" into eachother, but the first SVG has seemingly taken the space of a rectangle as the two "tips" of the SVGs line up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most simple solution to your problem is to lessen the viewBox height of the first `<svg>`, but to show the overflow. That way, the triangular form at the bottom will "slip" under the second `<svg>`

```css
svg {
    overflow:visible;
    display:block;
}
.cls-1 {
  fill: #190eae;
}
.cls-2 {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg-top" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
  <path id="bali-beautiful-beauty-433539" class="cls-1" d="M0,0H1920V1080L0,1250Z"/>
</svg>

<svg id="svg-bottom" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 960 1080.021" id="sectiona">
  <g id="Group_78" data-name="Group 78" transform="translate(-488 -3248.979)">
    <path id="Path_26" data-name="Path 26" class="cls-2" d="M-1-16.511l960-85.021V978.489l-960-85Z" transform="translate(489 3350.511)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Note how I have moved the styles outside the SVGs. They are part of the same DOM anyway, and if both quote the same class name, both styles will be applied to both paths. I've changed the class name for one of them, so that does not happen.

Another issue is that `<svg>` elements in HTML are inline-blocks. As such they have a line height, and if they are displayed one below the other (as happens here because their default width is 100%), that may lead to a small visible gap between their layout boxes. Setting `display:block` solves that.

Comment: The trick is in the CSS property `overflow:visible`, applied to (at least) the first svg element.

Comment: I am able to drop the top SVG by set pixel amounts but when I change this to use the view height/width it seemingly does not work, is there a way around this? Otherwise I am unable to shrink the website and have it be responsive

Comment: "when I change this to use the view height/width": I don't understand this. What are you doing?

Comment: When I change the viewbox's height or width I will need it to be relative to the viewport

Comment: I guess a better question may be: Is there a better way to have a website that is made up of alternating facing trapeziums without this method of using SVGs?

Comment: Are you aware how `viewBox` works? The only thing it does is establish an arbitrary coordinate system for the content of the SVG. It does not set the size its shown at on the screen. You give that with the CSS `width` and `height` properties applying to the `<svg>` element. The defaults are `width:100%;height:auto`. Afterwards, the viewBox is scaled to fit into the element. So, as it stands, the SVGs will always scale to the screen width, and their lower end will always coincide with the bottom of the viewBox. I think that is what you are trying to achieve.